# Есть ли разница между quit и exit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Функция [type](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#type) показывает, что [quit](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/constants.html#quit) и [exit](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/constants.html#exit) являются одним объектом:

```
print(type(quit), type(exit))
# <class '_sitebuiltins.Quitter'> <class '_sitebuiltins.Quitter'>
```

Функция [id](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#id) возвращает разные идентификаторы:

```
print(hex(id(quit)), hex(id(exit)))
# 0x18caae42b70 0x18caae50630
```

Функция [help](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#help) возвращает одинаковое описание:

```
Help on Quitter in module _sitebuiltins object:

class Quitter(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __call__(self, code=None)
 |      Call self as a function.
 |  
 |  __init__(self, name, eof)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  __repr__(self)
 |      Return repr(self).
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

[В документации](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/constants.html#quit) обе функции имеют общее описание

> ```
> quit(code=None)
> exit(code=None)
> ```
>
> Objects that when printed, print a message like “Use quit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) 
>           to exit”, and when called, raise SystemExit with the specified exit code.

---

Но разница ведь должна быть?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Короткий ответ** -- разницы нет, это объекты от одного класса `Quitter` и разница будет только в наименовании:

```
print(quit)
# Use quit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit

print(exit)
# Use exit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit
```

Думаю, `quit` и `exit` добавлены для удобства работы с интерпретатором.

---

Для большего понимания нужно посмотреть исходный код [_sitebuiltins.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bdac32e9fe25fdb97a7172a93aabd1ffead89462/Lib/_sitebuiltins.py#L13):

```
class Quitter(object):
    def __init__(self, name, eof):
        self.name = name
        self.eof = eof
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Use %s() or %s to exit' % (self.name, self.eof)
    def __call__(self, code=None):
        # Shells like IDLE catch the SystemExit, but listen when their
        # stdin wrapper is closed.
        try:
            sys.stdin.close()
        except:
            pass
        raise SystemExit(code)
```

А также исходный код [site.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bdac32e9fe25fdb97a7172a93aabd1ffead89462/Lib/site.py#L354):

```
def setquit():
    """Define new builtins 'quit' and 'exit'.
    These are objects which make the interpreter exit when called.
    The repr of each object contains a hint at how it works.
    """
    if os.sep == '\\':
        eof = 'Ctrl-Z plus Return'
    else:
        eof = 'Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF)'

    builtins.quit = _sitebuiltins.Quitter('quit', eof)
    builtins.exit = _sitebuiltins.Quitter('exit', eof)
```

---

Аналогичный ответ на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19504740/5909792)

Comment: Кстати, зачем тогда два варианта?

Comment: @Victor, думаю, для удобства работы с интерактивным интерпретатором -- кому-то первое, что придет в голову, чтобы выйти из консоли прописать `quit`, кому-то `exit`, а не `:q!` (шутка про vim). Например, встречал в графических программах в меню File варианты выхода и `Exit`, и `Quit`

Comment: Tипа `alias quit="exit"`

Comment: @Victor, именно

Comment: @Victor, когда хотите отредактировать что-то, убедитесь что ваша правка не делает хуже (цитата внутри цитаты это нечто). Посмотрите [историю правок вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1040686/revisions) и сравните вашу и мою правку (в режиме разметки и "в две колонки").